# What happens to 'object' after local scope?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am eager to know what happens to a object in .NET when it falls out of scope. Something like this:

```
class A
{
    ClassB myObjectB = new ClassB();
}
//what happens to object at this point here?
```

What happens in the memory? Does GC get called when it falls out of scope and loose it reference in the heap?

Comment: The GC reaps objects "at some point after they are no longer strongly reachable". This is a poor example, however, because `myObjectB` is only assigned when on a `new A` (which never occurs) and the "a" will keep the object named by `myObjectB` strongly-reachable as long as "a" is strongly-reachable itself.

Comment: "An object is *strongly reachable* if some thread can reach it [from a root] without traversing any [soft/weak/phantom] reference objects." (Here is the [bit in Java terms](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html), but it applies to C# as well, minus some of the reference "strength" levels.)

Comment: This code even does not compile.

Comment: @Aliostad if we make the reasonable assumption that a `ClassB` is elsewhere declared with an accessible parameterless constructor, the code does indeed compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens in the memory? Does GC get called when it falls out of scope and loose it reference in the heap?

No - the GC doesn't get called at this point.

What happens is that the object is left in memory, but is now "unrooted" - basically, there are no references to that object from any other object.  As such, the object is now *eligible* for garbage collection.

At some point in the future, the GC will run.  When this happens, the unrooted object will now be eligible for garbage collection.  Depending on which generation holds the object, it may or may not be cleaned at that point.  Eventually, if the program continues executing and if memory pressure causes the appropriate generation to be collected, the memory for that object will be reclaimed.

There is no definite point in time when this will happen (unless you explicitly call `GC.Collect`, which is a bad idea).  However, with managed code, you don't really need to worry about when this will happen.  Just assume that it will happen when and if appropriate for your specific application.

Comment: In Java the terms are strongly-reachable (and unreachable): do you know of any such "authoritative" terminology to use when talking about C#/CLR?

Comment: @pst I believe the spec uses "rooted", which is why I used the term.  It's a "Normal" handle to the object [vs. a Weak or Pinned handle, in the example above] (see GCHandle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx)

Comment: @pst C# Language spec uses "unused object" (Part 1, Introduction) to refer to unrooted objects....  Looking for CLI spec terminology now.

Comment: @pst CLI Spec uses "objects that are no longer reachable" - FYI

Comment: Thanks (for those following along, the CLI: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf). I can +1 the answer, although the term "unrooted" just doesn't sit terribly well with me when talking about object lifetimes.

Answer (score 3):

Following from pst's comment, a better example might be this:

```
void M() 
{ 
    ClassB myObjectB = new ClassB(); 
} 
//what happens to object at this point here?
```

In this example, `myObjectB` is a local variable rather than a field.  So, what happens when the local variable goes out of scope?  **Nothing!  Scope has nothing to do with object lifetime in C#.**

What really happens is that the JIT compiler decides to release the object *at some point.*  That can be *before the end of the variable's scope*, if the variable is not going to be used in the rest of the method.  Once the object is no longer referenced, as other answers have also mentioned, it becomes *eligible* for collection by the GC.  It is not actually collected until the GC runs (actually, until the GC collects the generation in which the object is living).

As pst implied, a field is a poor example because it will always be reachable whenever its containing object is reachable, so the separation between scope and object lifetime is even greater:

```
class A
{
    private object o = //whatever
}

void B()
{
    var a = new A();
    // here, the field o is not in scope, but the object it refers to is reachable and cannot be collected.
    GC.KeepAlive(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find "falling out of scope" to be a much more C++-specific way of thinking of things, where at the end of a given scope an object with automatic storage is freed and has its destructor called.

In the C# world, there's no "falling out of scope". Variables (read: names) exist in a certain scope, and that's it. The GC really has no concern for this; an object can be collected before the end of its name's scope even exits, or long afterwards depending on what references it and when the GC decides a collection is necessary.

The two concepts should then be divorced and reasoned about separately. Scoping is all about names, whereas garbage collection cares only about the reachability of objects. When an object is no longer reachable from one of the known roots, it will be scheduled for collection.

Comment: Well, yes and no - (removing optimization from the equation here) the object, in the example above, can't become unrooted until the reference goes out of scope (or was set to reference a different object or null).  I think it's unfair to say that the two concepts are completely separate - but it does have a very different meaning than C++ thinking.

Comment: @ReedCopsey but why are you removing optimization from the equation?  Most code is optimized.

Comment: The reference is "out of scope" anywhere outside of the class, since its name is confined there without further qualification. I think you're conflating lifetimes with scope, whereas I believe C# makes a certain distinction between the two. See: "•The scope of a member declared by a class-member-declaration (Section 10.2) is the class-body in which the declaration occurs. In addition, the scope of a class member extends to the class-body of those derived classes that are included in the accessibility domain (Section 3.5.2) of the member."

Comment: @phoog Yes - but optimization just rewrites the code in a way that the above will still happen, but potentially at a different point in time.  The issue is exactly the same with optimization, but the timing may be (slightly) different.

Comment: @ReedCopsey In fact, Eric Lippert has an entry on the subject which makes the distinction as well. Scope is about naming, not lifetime: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx

Comment: @MikeP Read his article - in his works, the two concepts have a "strong connection"  I'm not arguing that they are the same, but they are related/connected.

Comment: @ReedCopsey And because optimization makes the timing different, meaning that the object can become unrooted before the reference goes out of scope, MikeP's answer is correct.  It's a bit like he's saying "the flight may arrive early because of tailwinds" and you're saying "leaving tailwinds out of the equation, that statement is incorrect."

Comment: @phoog The optimization cannot make a functional change to the program - from the point of view of understanding the concepts involved, understanding the scope of the local variable does have a strong impact on understanding the potential lifetime of the object referenced by that variable.  That was my only point...

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing referencing the object, it gets eventually collected by GC. The thing is, you can't predict WHEN exactly it will happen. You just know, it will happen.

Comment: @Raj, that's exactly the problem. You can't tell for sure with c#. This is not C++, where you can control every bit of your application. If you need that behaviour, maybe C# isn't right for you. Others explained it using more words, but the principle is still the same. Probably the most precise answer to your question is: "eventually".

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Garbage Collection happens at 3 distinct generations (0, 1, or 2). When each of these is collected depends on how much resources are needed by the OS.

A call to GC.Collect() will collect all of the available resources but it is possible to define which generation of resources to collect.